# Как лучше импортировать модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, модули

Есть например модуль - **math**, и из него я хочу импортировать только некоторые.
Как лучше делать?

Так?

```
from math import *
#Которые я допустим использую:
pi
e
sqrt
cos
```

```
import math
#И потом я их тоже использую...
math.pi
math.e
math.sqrt
math.cos
```

Или лучше вообще вот так?

```
from math import pi, e, sqrt, cos
#И потом я их тоже использую...
pi
e
sqrt
cos
```

Или как-то по другому?

Есть ли разница в скорости программы, или это одно и тоже? Да и как вообще лучше делать?

Comment: Нет никакого правильного, самого лучшего способа. Не рекомендуют импортировать через звездочку. А импортировать через `import module` или `from module import name` - без разницы. В случае однобуквенных переменных, типа e, лучше все же использовать `import math`, `math.e`, чтобы было понятно, что это константа из модуля `math`, а не просто какая-то однобуквенная переменная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этот вариант самый правильный:

```
from math import pi, sqrt
```

Причины:

1. Иногда имена функций в модулях обозначаются одинаковыми именами и после этого начинается большая путаница. Этот вариант будет наглядно показывать все имена функций и вы быстро найдете ошибку.
2. Также не забывайте, что при компиляции файла в exe весь модуль **math** будет скачиваться в ваш .exe файл. В итоге ваша программа будет весить больше, а способ, который указан выше будет скачивать только нужные функции. В итоге, ваша программа (.exe) будет весить меньше.
   Но если вы используете много функций модуля (>50%) или делайте например тематическое приложение на основе **math** (например калькулятор), то лучше импортировать так:

   ```
   from math import *
   ```

В общем, конечно разницы нет, но вот есть некоторые рекомендации, основанные на личном опыте.

Comment: А скорость выполнения программы как-то меняется? Есть разница? 
Именно, если не компилировать в .exe

Comment: Нету. Как бы вы модуль не импортировали время выполнения функции останется  неизменной

Comment: *скачивать только нужные функции и в итоге ваша программа(.exe) будет весить меньше* - **враки**. модуль загружается целиком в любом случае